# Persisting Application Version in Logs Across All Threads in Spring Boot 3.1.5 with WebFlux and SLF4J

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, slf4j

I'm working on a Spring Boot 3.1.5 project that uses WebFlux and SLF4J for logging. My goal is to include the application version number in all log entries generated throughout the application. To achieve this, I tried adding the version attribute to the Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) within a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` in the main application class. However, this approach only includes the version in logs produced by the main thread and not in those generated by other threads in the reactive context of the application.

How can I correctly register this version value in all logs produced by the application, ensuring it's included in logs from all threads, not just the main one? Is there a specific approach or configuration in Spring WebFlux that enables consistent MDC propagation across different threads?

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.